# List not refreshing after item had been deleted

Tags: angular

So im trying to make my lists refresh in my view after an item has been deleted but it doesnt seem to work. The item is delete is working as intended because when i refresh the page manually the item is deleted correctly.

Here is my component class.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe} from '@angular/core';
import { Bootcamp } from './Bootcamp';
import { Bootcamptest } from './Bootcamptest';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-bootcamptest',
    styleUrls: ['./Scripts/Css/Testcss.css'],
    template: `

  <section>
    <section *ngIf="isLoading && !errorMessage">
    Loading our hyperdrives!!! Retrieving data...
  </section>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
           naam
        </th>
        <th>
            description
        </th>
        <th>
           begindatum
        </th>
        <th>
           eindatum
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let _bootcamp of bootcamp ">
        <td >
          {{_bootcamp.naam}}
        </td>
         <td >
       {{_bootcamp.description}}

        </td>
         <td >
          {{_bootcamp.begindatum | date:"dd/MM/yy"}}
        </td>
        <td >
     {{_bootcamp.einddatum | date:"dd/MM/yy"}}
        </td>

    </tr>


</table>


      <ul>
        <!-- this is the new syntax for ng-repeat -->
        <li *ngFor="let _bootcamp of bootcamp" >
            <a  (click)="selectBootcamp(_bootcamp)">
          {{_bootcamp.IdBootcamp}}
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <section *ngIf="errorMessage">
        {{errorMessage}}
      </section>

<section *ngIf="selectedBootcamp">
    <h2>You selected:  {{selectedBootcamp.naam}}</h2>
    <h3>Description</h3>
    <p>
       {{selectedBootcamp.naam}} 
    </p>
  </section>

 <a routerLink="/bootcampsmaken" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Create Bootcamp</a>
 <a routerLink="/dagpuntmaken" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Dagpunt maken</a>
 <div class="agenda">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Begindatum</th>
                        <th>Einddatum</th>
                        <th>Bootcamp</th>
                        <th>Wat houdt die in?</th> 
                        <th>Details</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- Single event in a single day -->
                    <tr *ngFor="let _bootcamp of bootcamp" >
                        <td  class="agenda-date" class="active" rowspan="1">
                            <div class="dayofmonth"> {{_bootcamp.begindatum | date:"dd"}} </div>
                            <div class="dayofweek"> {{_bootcamp.begindatum | date:"EEEE"}}</div>
                            <div class="shortdate text-muted">{{_bootcamp.begindatum | date:"MMMM"}}, {{_bootcamp.begindatum | date:"y"}}</div>
                        </td>
                            <td  class="agenda-date" class="active" rowspan="1">
                            <div class="dayofmonth"> {{_bootcamp.einddatum | date:"dd"}} </div>
                            <div class="dayofweek"> {{_bootcamp.einddatum | date:"EEEE"}}</div>
                            <div class="shortdate text-muted">{{_bootcamp.einddatum | date:"MMMM"}}, {{_bootcamp.einddatum | date:"y"}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="agenda-time">
                                  {{_bootcamp.naam}}
                        </td>
                        <td class="agenda-events">
                            <div class="agenda-event">
                                     {{_bootcamp.description}}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="details">
                                      <a  routerLink="/bootcampsmaken" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Details</a>
                                        <a  (click)="DeleteBootcamp(_bootcamp.IdBootcamp)" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>




  `
})

export class Bootcamplistcomponent implements OnInit {
    bootcamp: Bootcamp[] = [];
    selectedBootcamp: Bootcamp;
    errorMessage: string = '';
    isLoading: boolean = true;


    constructor(private bootcamptest: Bootcamptest) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.bootcamptest
            .getAll()
            .subscribe(
         /* happy path */ p => this.bootcamp = p,
         /* error path */ e => this.errorMessage = e,
         /* onComplete */() => this.isLoading = false);
    }
    selectBootcamp(bootcamp: Bootcamp) {
        this.selectedBootcamp = bootcamp;

    }
    DeleteBootcamp(id: number) {
        this.bootcamptest.deleteselected(id);
        this.bootcamptest
            .getAll()
            .subscribe(
        /* happy path */ p => this.bootcamp = p,
         /* error path */ e => this.errorMessage = e,
         /* onComplete */() => this.isLoading = false);

    }
}
```

Edit 1: My service class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Bootcamp } from './Bootcamp';


const BOOTCAMP: Bootcamp[] = [

];


@Injectable()

export class Bootcamptest {
    //private baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:54220/Bootcampdata';
    private baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:62195/api';


    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    create(body: object): Promise<Bootcamp> {
        return this.http
            .post(`${this.baseUrl}/Bootcamps`, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: this.headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => res.json().data)
            .catch(handleError);
    }
    deleteselected(body: number): Promise<number> {
        return this.http
            .delete(`${this.baseUrl}/Bootcamps/${body}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => res.json().data)
            .catch(handleError);


    }
    getAll(): Observable<Bootcamp[]> {
        let bootcamp$ = this.http
            .get(`${this.baseUrl}/Bootcamps`, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
            .map(mapBootcamps)
            .catch(handleError);

        return bootcamp$;


    }
    deleteselected2(body: number) {
        return this.http
            .delete(`${this.baseUrl}/Bootcamps/${body}`)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }

    private getHeaders() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

        return headers;
    }


}

function mapBootcamps(response: Response): Bootcamp[] {
    // uncomment to simulate error:
    // throw new Error('ups! Force choke!');

    // The response of the API has a results
    // property with the actual results
    console.log(response.json())
    return response.json().map(toBootcamp)


} function toBootcamp(r: any): Bootcamp {
    //  var value = new Date(parseInt(r.Begindatum.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, '')));
    //var value2 = new Date(parseInt(r.Einddatum.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, '')));
    let bootcamp = <Bootcamp>({
        IdBootcamp: r.IdBootcamp,
        naam: r.Naam,
        description: r.Description,
       // begindatum: value.getMonth() +
        //1 +
        //"/" +
       // value.getDate() +
      //  "/" +
        //value.getFullYear(),
        begindatum : r.Begindatum,
        einddatum: r.Einddatum
    });

    console.log('Parsed bootcamp:', bootcamp);
    return bootcamp;
}

// to avoid breaking the rest of our app
// I extract the id from the person url
function extractId(Bootcamps: any) {
    let extractedId = Bootcamps.url.replace('http://localhost:49969/api/Bootcamps/', '').replace('/', '');
    return parseInt(extractedId);
}

function mapBootcamp(response: Response): Bootcamp {
    // toPerson looks just like in the previous example

    return toBootcamp(response.json());
}

// this could also be a private method of the component class
function handleError(error: any) {
    // log error
    // could be something more sofisticated
    let errorMsg = error.message || `Error met het laden van data`
    console.error(errorMsg);

    // throw an application level error
    return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
}
```

Comment: `this.bootcamptest.deleteselected(id)` what is the function definition for this?

Answer (score 0):

call you getList method after successfull deletion of item like this

```js
    constructor(private bootcamptest: Bootcamptest) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getList();
    }
    getList(){
        this.bootcamptest
            .getAll()
            .subscribe(
        /* happy path */ p => this.bootcamp = p,
         /* error path */ e => this.errorMessage = e,
         /* onComplete */() => this.isLoading = false);
    }

    selectBootcamp(bootcamp: Bootcamp) {
        this.selectedBootcamp = bootcamp;

    }

    DeleteBootcamp(id: number) {
        this.bootcamptest.deleteselected(id)
            .subscribe(res=>{
                //when you get status that item is deleted succesflly
                //call again this.getList();
                })
    }

}
```

Comment: Fetching the list once again in case of success sounds a bit overkill...

Comment: its upto you, whether you want to fetch data again from server or just splice object from array localy @n00dl3

Comment: So im trying to do what you say and i get the error "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<number>'. Is the way i spoken to the api to do my delete wrong?

Comment: error occurred because  `this.bootcamptest.deleteselected(id)` does't return anything i think so, if so than make function return something or get flag when your delete request is completed successfully , than call furthur process

Answer (score 0):

```
this.bootcamptest.deleteselected(id).subscribe(
        data => {
              let index = this.bootcamp.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
              this.bootcamp.splice(index,1);
                },
        err => {
            console.log('error');
         })
```